# ClosedXML How to get pivot table range?

Tags: c#, closedxml

I need to get the latest row used by a pivot table.

I tried:

```
mysheet.LastRowUsed().RowNumber();
```

and

```
mypivot.TargetCell.Address.RowNumber
```

but it doesn't seem to be working.

In Office object model the PivotTable has a TableRange2 property where you can get this info...